# How to copy data from a 1 x 1 double timeseries to a 1 D Lookup Table in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been asked to look at a Matlab project.  I'll link sceenshots to clarify the problem.  I need to create a 1 D Lookup table with the data from a 1 x 1 double timeseries from another model that has been supplied.  One problem is that there are a lot of data points (12500).  Is it possible to copy these points across without having to drag the mouse down over the whole 12500 points?  Someone has actually tried this dragging the mouse over all the points method and said it didn't work anyway, but I don't really want to try it myself, as it would be way to cumbersome for my liking, even if it did work.

Here is an example of what the 1 x 1 double timeseries looks like (just using 5 points instead of 12500 for simplicity's sake):

[image: 1 x 1 double timeseries]

Here is the model with the 1D look up table highlighted in blue at the left:

[image: 1D loookup table in Matlab model]

Here is what the 1-D lookup table looks like when opened:

[image: Contents of 1-D lookup table]

Any insight appreciated.

I've worked out how to copy the data from the timeseries table (actually from the input to this, which is a 1 x 1 struct), but he problem is that the values have no commas between them and the 1-D lookup table requires commas.

Note that the problem has now been solved using Excel, although not by the method I was trying to make work in the question.  An answer has been posted which may work, but I'm not sure if i will go to the trouble of attempting to implement it or not at this stage.  However, if need be and all being well, I will either do that or delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can import a look-up table object (`Simulink.LookupTable`-object) from both, the [MATLAB workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/import-data-from-the-matlab-workspace.html) or directly from [Excel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-to-import-data-from-an-excel-spreadsheet.html).

If you want to automate it, it basically comes down to these two points:
"

- Open the model containing the lookup table block and in the Modeling tab, select Model Settings.
- In the Model Properties dialog box, in the Callbacks tab, click PostLoadFcn callback in the model callbacks list.

... the next time you open the model, Simulink® invokes the callback and imports the data.
"

Comment: Thanks.  I've followed the instructions you gave.  I just want clarify that I need to get the data from the timeseries in 1 Simulink model and transfer it to a separate Simulink Model.  Also, could you please clarify exactly how I get the look-up table object that has been imported or created as a result of fiddling with the Model properties in the way you described.  Oh and by the way, I noticed when I tried to copy and paste the 12500 data points into the look up table before you gave this reply that it was unable to hold that many in the input field: not sure if that will be a problem.

Comment: I guess it shouldn't be a problem, if I understand you correctly.  Oh and just to be absolutely clear,  I need to get the data from the 1 x 1 double timeseries in 1 Simulink model and transfer it to a Lookup Table in a separate Simulink Model.

Comment: It seems to me that the process you describe how to do in your answer is actually the reverse of what I'm after, however.  You describe how to import a look up table.  I actually want to import data from a 1 x 1 double timeseries in 1 project and transfer it into a look up table in another project.

Comment: OK, so you create a time-series in simulink and want to use it as a look-up table in a separate simulink block/model? I recommend to build this as two separate simulink models (you need to run the first part before the second part anyway to obtain the required look-up table). If you have the first as a separate model, you an simply use the ["to workspace"/"simout" block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) and load this again for the second model (it needs to be in the workspace but you don't need a dedicated block for this

Comment: Yes that's right.  Ok thanks.  The problem has actually been solved using Excel now, but I may pass on what you said and look at it further.

Answer (score 0):

After a little thought I feel like the answer is actually fairly trivial: it just can't be done.  The input field of the look up table just can't hold 12500 points, most of which have 9 or so decimal places, so there's no way to do this.

This isn't to say there's no way to put the data into the model: this can be done using Excel.